# Releasatory? Releaseful?

Tags: adjectives

What would be a good word to describe something (like sex) which gives a lot of release.

The sense is "rewarding, emotionally fulfilling and physically ...releaseful?"

Comment: Mike, it is a good idea to wait a while, say a couple of days, before "accepting" an answer, so more members get to view and try to answer. Also, the asker stands a better chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: Releasatory? Releaseful? I don't think any such words exist. However, a slang word *releasation* is defined in http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Releasation

Comment: Suggestion: Start with your message: what you are trying to express, instead of starting with the words. In particular: release of **what**? Once you know that, you can look for words specific to (release of) that *<SOMETHING>*. IOW, it is the *<SOMETHING>* that is most important here, presumably, so use that as your starting point.

Comment: I would have said "releasing", but that appears to not be a word as an adjective.  "Relieving" seems closest.

Comment: *orgasmic*. Because it's sex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [unwinding](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwind):  (from M-W)

To unwind:

> - to relax and stop thinking about work, problems, etc.

also [satisfying](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/satisfying):

> - providing abundant nourishment; "a hearty meal"; "good solid food";
> - that  gratifies  the need, desire, or expectation of.

Comment: Went with "ultimately rewarding, emotionally fulfilling and physically satisfying." 'cause sounding right was more important than specifically having the sought meaning.

Answer (score 19):

I'd use *cathartic*, from

ca·thar·sis
 noun \kə-ˈthär-səs\

: the act or process of releasing a strong emotion (such as pity or fear) especially by expressing it in an art form
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/catharsis

I think MW overstates the importance of art though.

Comment: Not overstating really but recognizing the usage. +1 all the same.

Comment: +1 The term is particularly associated with art because this figurative use of the original medical sense derives from Aristotle's use in the *Poetics*.

Comment: Is this not normally a positive emotion Vita a negative process?  Or is that a connotation that I've picked up myself?

Comment: @Pureferret Not that I'm aware of. I've most often seen catharsis used as the result of a positive process. When the process is negative, phrases like *guilty pleasure* or *stress release* seem more common.

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for "***relieving***". Merriam-Webster gives the following definition of "relieve" as an intransitive verb:

> ***[relieve](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relieve)***: to bring or give relief

Comment: thought about relieve, but sounds too medicinal.

Comment: I would quote Ben Harper for a use of `relieve` in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking the most suitable word is probably ***relaxing*** - assuming the effect OP refers to is much bound up with *taut/tight/contracted muscles* that need to *relax/loosen up*.

Comment: That's much too passive to describe sex, though. (Different strokes for different folks, I guess.)

Comment: @200_success: I don't understand what "too passive" means there. I prefaced my answer with "technically speaking" because in common parlance people are more likely to say *[something] is **relaxing*** when they mean *mentally* (as opposed to *physically*, which is the context explicitly required here). So we'd be more likely to say [*Distalgesic*](http://www.netdoctor.co.uk/aches-and-pains/medicines/distalgesic.html) is a *"muscle **relaxant**"*, rather than call it *relaxing*.

Comment: _Relaxing_ sounds like you lie there like a [dead fish](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dead%20Fish).

Comment: Relaxing as a description of an activity doesn't imply passivity.  Hard physical work to relieve stress can be relaxing, high-energy sports can be relaxing, etc.  This is a good answer in my books.

Answer (score 1):

Sated, as in satisfied, fully.

Comment: *You* may be sated or satisfied, but the question is asking about the *activity* which brings satiation or satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

> - invigorating - Making one feel healthy and full of energy. [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/invigorating?searchDictCode=all)
> - revitalizing - giving new life or vigor to. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revitalizing?show=0&t=1417105731)

"Bad sex is good, and good sex is invigorating."

"Spending two weeks at the spa was really revitalizing for my shattered nerves."

Comment: "The *best* sex is debilitating." +1 to off-set the prudes and for the best two words here.